# Overlay Fixed Size Form Field Over Fixed Size Image

Tags: html, css

I have an image that fixes itself to 100% of the page width.  It stays the same size (on the screen) no matter what resizing the user does in their browser.

I now need to add a single Enter Your Name form field on top of the image.  However, I want the text and form field sizing and position to stay the same no matter what the user does to resize their browser window.  This is important because I need to overlay the form field table just perfectly on top of the image or else it will look bad.

Here's my current CSS:

```
.fixedimage img{
    width:100% !important;
    height:auto;
    display:block;
}
```

Here's my current HTML:

```
<TABLE WIDTH="100%" CELLPADDING="0" CELLSPACING="0" BORDER="0">
<TR>
<TD WIDTH="100%">
<div class="fixedimage">
<center><img src="FixedImage.jpg"></center>
</div>
</TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>
```

How would I overlay the table in a particular spot on top of the FixedImage.jpg?  And how would I keep it being the same size when a user resizes or zooms in/out in their browser window?

Thanks for your help with this!!!

Comment: The center tag is deprecated, I would suggest using something else.

Comment: Set the background image of the container and add the form part html in the container.This will give you the output you asked for.

Comment: I would suggest that a _tabular design_ is also deprecated. You will find much difficulty in achieving a responsive design, as it seems you'd like, while using tables.  Also, please don't capitalize element names or attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/nV7tP/1/

**CSS**:

```
.fixedimage{
    width:100% !important;
    height:auto;
    display:block;
    background:url(http://www.hdwallpaperspick.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/beautiful-autumn-scenery-723-2.jpg);
    background-position:50% 50%;
    background-size:cover;
}
.fixedimage form{
    width:100%;
    color:white;
    font-size:40px;
    text-align:center;
}
.fixedimage form input{
    width:250px;
    height:30px;
}
```

---

Response to the comment below:

Try this fiddle to show the entire background image:

http://jsfiddle.net/nV7tP/2/

```
.fixedimage{
    position:absolute;
    width:100% !important;
    height:auto;
    display:block;
    font-size:40px;
}
.fixedimage img{
    position:absolute;
}
.fixedimage form{
    position:absolute;
    width:100%;
    color:white;
    text-align:center;
}
.fixedimage form input{
    width:250px;
    height:30px;
}
```

Note : It would be better if you use the CSS of first posted fiddle.Its the type of CSS mostly used in present popular sites.

---

Set the image *width to 100%* .This will give the output you asked:

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nV7tP/5/

or if you want a container with minimum width see this http://jsfiddle.net/nV7tP/6/ .

Comment: Thank you.  However, 2 questions:

Comment: 1. It now seems to be making only part of the container/background image show up rather than all of it.  It only shows the part around the form since it's a background image now.

Comment: 2. When I zoom in/out with my browser, it now shrinks the size of the text around the form field.  I'm looking for something that stays large just like the background image itself does.  I hope this clarifies what I'm trying to do.  Thank you so much for your help!!!

Comment: do you want your text to be responsive?

Comment: I'm not a fulltime developer, but yes, I believe that's the case.  Basically, the image I'm using only has a small area of maybe 300px wide by 200px tall that is clear enough for the table to be inserted that asks for their name.  Therefore, precision is key.  If someone zooms in/out of their browser or if it's not perfectly in that area, it wouldn't look right.

Comment: Maybe what I'm trying to do isn't possible with text.  I'm not sure.

Comment: @user3161669 i will suggest you to use the first fiddle CSS that i posted.

Comment: Ok, thank you.  The text still changes as a user zooms in/out, but maybe that's forced on the text by the browsers.  Anyway, thank you!

Comment: Ok, I did that.  One last question... if I go with fiddle 1, then is there a way to make the image show up all of its height?  Fiddle 2 doesn't conform the image to 100% width.

Comment: Oh ok.  I don't want to do that.  So just to confirm... there is no way to show an image fixed-width 100% of screen size (height adjusts based on width) and then overlay a form field on top of that?

Comment: Check the third fiddle if it is what you want

Comment: Sorry to bother you.  One more question.  It now looks like the bg image goes down to 100% of the bg image height.  However, the content below the table and div structure gets put under the bg image in the div.  In other words, the text that I have after that section (in the HTML code) doesn't show up because it's hidden under the bg image.  It's kind of strange why that's happening

Comment: Try using `z-index:100;` property of css for the form element containing text.